# How do I pass username and password to an httpWebRequest in silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, httpwebrequest, ascii

How do I pass username and password to an **HttpWebRequest** in **Silverlight 4**.

since the HttpWebRequst class in silverlight does not implement **Credentials** property, therefore i am unable to authenticate my user.

one  way I found was, to pass credentials in header using Authorization header, but it requires **ASCII** encoded value, which is not supported in Silverlight.

any other alternatives???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks, I got the solution, I had to write following line before creating the WebRequest object. :)

> WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://":, WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should just try it.  **All** http headers are by specification ASCII.  Hence the fact that `HttpWebRequest` supports a `Headers` collection that accepts a string for a header value implies that the string will be converted appropriately when sent in a HTTP session.